# Unrecognised hadoop major version 1.2.1 error - Hive and impala jdbc connection using jayadebeapi

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, hive, impala

I am facing error while running python script which connects hive using jdbc connection string.

```
import jaydebeapi

database='testdb'
driver='org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver'
server='ip'
principal='something'
port=10000

# JDBC connection string
url=("jdbc:hive2://" + server + ":" + str(port)
+ "/"+ database +";principal=" + principal + ";")

#Connect to HiveServer2 
conn=jaydebeapi.connect(driver, url)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute SQL query
sql="select * from testdb limit 10"
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
print (results)
cursor.close()
```

Error i am getting :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/rkumbar/hive-impala-jdbc/jar_files/hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.0.1-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/rkumbar/hive-impala-jdbc/jar_files/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "org.jpype.JPypeContext.java", line -1, in org.jpype.JPypeContext.callMethod
  File "Method.java", line 498, in java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  File "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java", line 43, in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
  File "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", line 62, in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
  File "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java", line -2, in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0
  File "DriverManager.java", line 270, in java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
  File "DriverManager.java", line 664, in java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
  File "HiveDriver.java", line 107, in org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect
  File "HiveConnection.java", line 210, in org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>
Exception: Java Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hive-jdbc.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn=jaydebeapi.connect(driver, url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 412, in connect
    jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py", line 230, in _jdbc_connect_jpype
    return jpype.java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, *dargs)
jaydebeapi.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://<ip>/testdb;principal=hive/ip;: Unrecognized Hadoop major version number: 1.2.1
```

**My hadoop version: Hadoop 3.0.0-cdh6.3.2 ,
my hive version : Hive 2.1.1-cdh6.3.2**

Jars i used

- commons-codec-1.4.jar
- hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar
- hive-common-2.3.7.jar
- hive-service-rpc-2.1.0.jar
- libthrift-0.13.0.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar
- hive-jdbc-2.1.1-cdh6.0.1-standalone.jar
- httpclient-4.2.5.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- guava-11.0.2.jar
- hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar
- hive-metastore-3.1.0-sources.jar
- httpcore-4.2.4.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
- hadoop-auth-3.0.0.jar
- hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-3.0.0.jar
- hive-service-0.13.1.jar
- libfb303-0.9.0.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

hadoop-client-2.2.0 nor hadoop-core-1.2.1 work with Hadoop 3.0

You need to align all versions of your JARs correctly, as well as all the dependencies. This is very difficult to do manually.

---

Not sure why you're trying to manually add jar files since pyhive or impyla would make you more sense

Otherwise, use pyspark

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to test jdbc driver hive  connection using python which can be used in non cdh cluster , i know it will work with impyla and pyspark

Comment: CDH doesn't matter. Python shouldn't need to use JDBC. You should use ODBC or Thrift-based clients. My answer is still correct. You cannot mix JAR versions